# Display Date dd/mm/yy in php with time from date/time

Tags: php, mysql

I store the date and time in mysql as a date/time field which has this format:  2012-03-12 14:51:26, what i am trying to do is simply rearrange the DD/MM/YY to look like this.

When i use the following code, it just gives me a date wrong format warning.

```
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the MySQL timestamp to a unix timestamp, then you can use the date() function to output it in whatever format you like:

```
$unixTimestamp = strtotime($mysqlDate);
echo date($dateFormat, $unixTimestamp);
```

See the date format strings here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

If you are just displaying the date you can supply a certain format in the SQL query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("%d/%m/%Y", date_column) FROM table
```

Comment: In this case, you can also go with SELECT DATE_FORMAT("%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s", date_column) FROM table  to match the question

Answer (score 1):

First, convert it to a Unix timestamp (which I find to be all around better than a date_time field for a lot of reasons), then use PHP's date function.

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: The problem with a unix timestamp within the database is that you cannot apply any of the SQL date functions without converting it to a datetime first

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
```

And read about [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

this will work.

```
$date = date_create("2012-03-24 17:45:12");
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: thanks but this just prints the date you have entered in the date_create part?

Comment: oh yea. sorry. this works though. <?php
$date = "2012-03-24 17:45:12";
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
?>